# Need help regarding running multiple queries in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some queries that I want to run in a sequential Manner. Is it possible to schedule multiple queries under one scheduled query in Big Query? Thanks

[image: CONCEPT PICTURE]tack.imgur.com/flUN4.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Not currently, but an alpha program for scripting support in BigQuery was announced at Google Cloud Next in April. You can follow the [relevant feature request for updates](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36955074). In the meantime, you could consider using Cloud Composer to execute multiple sequential queries or an [App Engine cron](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) with some code to achieve sequential execution on a regular basis.

Edit (October 2019): [support for scripting and stored procedures is now in beta](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting). You can submit multiple queries separated with semi-colons and BigQuery is able to run them now.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need all of the intermediate tables and are just interested in the final output... consider using CTEs.

```
with first as (
    select *, current_date() as todays_date from <table1>
),
second as (
    select current_date(), concat(field1,field2) as new_field, count(*) as ct
    from first
    group by 1,2
)
select * from second
```

You can chain together as many of these as needed.

If you do need all of these intermediate tables materialized, you are venturing into ETL and orchestration tools (`dbt`, `airflow`, etc) or will need to write a custom script to execute several commands sequentially.

Comment: The following code worked for me: "With First As( select * from FRIDAY.Adserver where C_date = Current_date() ), Second As( select * from First JOIN FRIDAY.Matching_Table1 ON First.Placement_ExtID = Matching_Table1.string_field_1 OR First.Placement_ExtID = Matching_Table1.string_field_0 ), Tird As( Select *, CONCAT(Cast(Date as String),"-",Second.string_field_0) AS New_IDS from Second ) Select * from Tird" ........Can you plz tell me how can I add below code into the above code before I run the above mentioned code. "Update FRIDAY.Adserver SET C_date= current_date() where C_date is NULL)"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for, but I'm confident that you won't need to orchestrate many queries to do this.  It may be as simple to use the `INSERT...SELECT` syntax, like this:

```
INSERT INTO
  YourDataset.AdServer_Refine
SELECT
  Placement_ExtID,
  COALESCE(m.New_Ids,a.Placement_ExtID) AS New_Ids,
  m.Labels,
  CONCAT(Date," - ",New_Ids) AS Concatenated,
  a.Placement_strategy,
  a.Campaign_Id,
  a.Campaign,
  a.Cost,
  a.Impressions,
  a.Clicks,
  a.C_Date AS Current_date,
  a.Date
FROM
  YourDataset.AdServer AS a
  LEFT JOIN
  YourDataset.Matching AS m
  USING(Placement_ExtID)
WHERE
  a.Date = CURRENT_DATE()
```

This will insert all the rows that are output from `SELECT` portion of the query (and you can easily test the output by just running the `SELECT`).

Another option is to create a scheduled query that outputs to your desired table from the SELECT portion of the query above.

If that isn't doing what you're expecting, please clarify the question and leave a comment and I'm happy to try to refine the answer.

Comment: The following code worked for me:
"With First As( select * from FRIDAY.Adserver where C_date = Current_date() ),
Second As( select * from First JOIN FRIDAY.Matching_Table1 ON First.Placement_ExtID = Matching_Table1.string_field_1 OR First.Placement_ExtID = Matching_Table1.string_field_0 ),
Tird As( Select *, CONCAT(Cast(Date as String),"-",Second.string_field_0) AS New_IDS from Second ) Select * from Tird" ........Can you plz tell me how can I add below code into the above code before I run the above mentioned code.
"Update FRIDAY.Adserver SET C_date= current_date() where C_date is NULL)"

Comment: Because I want to update the C_date Column in the adserver table with the current date as when it gets imported from the cloud it has NULL values. So that the next day when the new data appends to this adserver table, I would again update the null values with Current date and take the rows with the current date and re-run the above code.
OR
DO you have any suggestion how can I have a column which can tell me the date on which the data has been fetched? Like each row contains the data when it has been fetched. I have tried the ingestion one it is not working.

Comment: @FawadAnsari If you just want the current date used whenever `C_Date` is `NULL`, you can update my code above to use `COALESCE(a.C_Date,CURRENT_DATE()) AS Current_date`.  `COALESCE` returns the first non-null parameter passed to it.

Comment: But I also want to update the C_date column with the current date in the adserver table. and then I want to pick only the data with the current date.